# SFML locked to 60 Hz on Linux?

Tags: linux, sfml

My SFML 1.6 application runs on 60 Hz on Ubuntu 11.10 with GNOME3, even though the maximum framerate and vsync is disabled. Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: oh god, that acronym is dirty...

Comment: @Fabian:  Which version of SFML are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try disabling compositing in your window manager. Or use a window manager like openbox and see if it still runs on 60Hz.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it really depends on the compositor in use.